# remove tc filter (Traffic Shaping)

Tags: filter, tc, traffic

How can I remove a single filter?

```
tc filter show dev peth1
```

shows

```
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 16 u32
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 16 u32 fh 800: ht divisor 1
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 16 u32 fh 800::800 order 2048 key ht 800 bkt 0 flowid 1:2 match 5bd6aaf9/ffffffff at 12
```

Why does that not work?:

```
tc filter del dev peth1 pref 1 protocol ip handle 800:800 u32
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old post, but for reference, it wouldn't work for a few reasons:

- The priority should be 16 and not 1
- The filter handle should be 800::800 and not 800:800
- You must supply the parent qdisc that the filter is attached to

This should work:

```
tc filter del dev peth1 parent 1: handle 800::800 prio 16 protocol ip u32
```

Comment: I did not think that I ever get an answer :D Thank you!